# Limit a Linux port to single not specific IP address using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I’m setting up a service that i need to limit the connections per port.

each client can have multiple connections so i want to limit it using IP address but the IP address is not unique and it may change. (i know multiple clients can connect behind NAT and its OK)

is there a way to do it using iptables?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use two limit checks (perhaps `--connlimit-saddr`):

- The first check is for the total number of connections (connlimit-mask 0), and has a limit of 0 (zero). If the server is still under the limit (e.g. if `--connlimit-upto 0` succeeds), accept the connection. If the check says you're above zero, do the second check.
- The second check is for an individual IP address (connlimit-mask 32 for IPv4 or 128 for IPv6). The limit is also zero connections, but the result is inverted: if you're *above* the limit, accept the connection. If you're at or below the limit, reject the new connection.

If the total check said "above zero" in step 1, but the individual check doesn't give the same result, that means all current connections are from a different address than the new one.

If I got the logic right, this should work:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j LIMITED
-A LIMITED -4 -m connlimit --connlimit-saddr --connlimit-mask 0 --connlimit-upto 0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIMITED -4 -m connlimit --connlimit-saddr --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-above 0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIMITED -j REJECT
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work but i guess this is the best way to do it

Comment: The problem is the second part it accepts all connections

Comment: Hmm, I'll need to re-think it.